# Can I use a 4x4 concrete post holder to install a gate?

Tags: concrete, gates, gate-post

I would like to install a 10' gate across my driveway to keep my 16 month old from running his tiny butt into traffic. The gate I intend to purchase is this one, with some PVC lattice to prevent climb-through:

[image]

Basic details from retailer's website:

6 bar economy galvanized tube gate

Made from 1-3/4" round high-tensile strength galvanized tubing with superior continuous- welded saddle joints

All material 20 gauge

Vertical galvanized "z" braces

Comes complete with hinges, hinge pins, and 22" snap chain

50" high

Can I use a 4x4 post holder that relies on concrete anchors to install the 4x4 pressure treated post I intend to hold the gate? I would think the torsional strain would pose a problem, and the driveway is rather uneven in sections so a "gate wheel" may not always be able to take the weight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Those holders give virtually no torsional support. Your gate will tear it right down. Plan on robust posts in a substantial concrete footing to carry that torque load.

Either that and do what I did and run some snow fence on a pair of 1/4" vinyl-coated cable. The gate won't contain a toddler, and the snow fence wouldn't either, but it gives a visual barrier and slows them down. That's the main goal. The rest is handled by good parental discipline.

You're going to find the toddler years whisking away in no time. Do you really want that big gate there anyway?

Comment: This is only our first of 2 or 3 planned kids, and he LOVES running to the street. Not even an amazing Pirate Ship Water Table is enough to keep him in the large grassy yard for long. The gate would serve to block him from becoming bumper paste while we run inside the house for 30 seconds to check on supper. I just don't have an extra 3000$ kicking around for a beautiful gate that's professionally installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have aprox 3' in the ground and cement around the post it will work (I have a 14' tube gate on a 4x4 just 1 post). I have quite a few of these on my property (+ 10 at least to fence horses) where I could not sink the post deep enough I added a small 6" tire to the end of the gate it carries the load.

Comment: I don't have the tools or time to cut out the cement to do a full buried post.  I'll just head back to the drawing board.  Thanks for the tip!